# Extract data from XML attribute and loop in foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I am not able to get this foreach to loop. It is only returning the first value, lego. How can I make it loop and return both lego and playmobil.

XML

```
<product product-id="000000000100165001">
    <customattributes>
        <customattribute attributeid="brand1">lego</customattribute>
        <customattribute attributeid="isBulky">false</customattribute>
        <customattribute attributeid="isDropShip">false</customattribute>
    </customattributes> 
</product>
<product product-id="000000000100164001">
    <customattributes>
        <customattribute attributeid="brand1">playmobil</customattribute>
        <customattribute attributeid="isBulky">false</customattribute>
        <customattribute attributeid="isDropShip">false</customattribute>
    </customattributes> 
</product>
```

PHP

```
foreach ($xml->product->customattributes->customattribute as $rating) {
  switch((string) $rating['attributeid']) { // Get attributes as element indices
    case 'brand1':
      echo $rating;
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access `$xml->product->customattributes`, the syntax is short-hand for `$xml->product[0]->customattributes`. That is, you're only looping over the `<customattribute>` tags from the first product.

If you want to loop over both products *and* their attributes, you'll need to use two loops:

```
foreach ($xml->product as $product) {
  foreach ($product->customattributes->customattribute as $rating) {
  ...
```

See https://eval.in/1045244 for a full example

Comment: That worked. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Iainn